# How do I avoid the AWS CLI completion UI for complete commands?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, bash-completion

How does the AWS CLI command completion setting `cli_auto_prompt = on-partial` work? In my `~/.aws/config` I have

```
[default]
region = us-west-2
output = json
cli_auto_prompt = on-partial
cli_history = enabled
cli_timestamp_format = iso8601
```

But when I enter complete commands such as

```
aws iam list-groups
```

and press enter, I still get the completion UI. As I understand [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html#cli-configure-files-settings), which says

> `on-partial` uses partial auto-prompt mode. If a command is incomplete or cannot be run due to client-side validation errors, auto-prompt is used. This mode is particular useful if you have pre-existing scripts, runbooks, or you only want to be auto-prompted for commands you are unfamiliar with rather than prompted on every command.

I should not have had the completion UI interrupt me, and instead the command should just have been executed.

How do I avoid the AWS CLI completion UI for complete commands?

---

(The other settings, such as `output`, and `cli_history` all work as expected, and respond to changes made in `~/.aws/config`.)

---

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/2.7.11 Python/3.10.5 Darwin/20.6.0 source/x86_64 prompt/on
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0)
$ which -a aws
/usr/local/bin/aws
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/aws
lrwxr-xr-x  1 Tax  admin  31 Jun 25 09:50 /usr/local/bin/aws -> ../Cellar/awscli/2.7.11/bin/aws
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Using `aws-cli/2.9.11` and running `aws iam list-groups` executes the command without opening the auto-prompt UI. Typing, for example, `aws iam list-` and hitting Enter opens the auto-prompt UI, as expected. `cli_auto_prompt = on-partial` is set. Maybe it was a bug in the AWS CLI version and updating helps?

Comment: @weibeld I'm not sure what you're saying. The second sentence does not describe the issue, nor is it an example of the first. What happens if you type `aws iam list-groups` and hit enter? (aws-cli/2.9.13 Python/3.11.1 Darwin/20.6.0 source/x86_64 prompt/off)

Comment: The comment says the following: `aws iam list-groups` --> no completion UI. `aws iam list-` (incomplete command) --> completion UI.

Comment: @weibeld (The use of "for example" there is what's confusing. I see what you intended now though.) I get different behavior: if I type a complete command, the command does not execute; instead the completion dropdown intervenes, makes me select the command again, and makes me select enter again. So it takes 3 enters (or 2 and 1 down arrow) to execute an already complete command. What's your full config?

Comment: Config (`~/.aws/config`) includes just one line of settings: `cli_auto_prompt = on-partial`. Are you sure you don't have the [`AWS_CLI_AUTO_PROMPT`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html#envvars-list-aws_cli_auto_prompt) env var set to `on` somewhere, as this overrides the setting in the config file?

Comment: Genius! Yes, I do have `AWS_CLI_AUTO_PROMPT` set to `on` (in my `.bash_profile`). Bit getting rid of that I can no longer get `aws` do do anything! Any attempt (complete or incomplete) just dumps a few blank lines and a footer with some F-command choices, any of which result in exiting with no result. And — weirdly — restoring it I still get the same thing! AWS cli no longer works at all. I'll explore a bit more but somethings badly messed up.

Comment: @weibeld That did the trick! (After reinstalling AWS CLI.) I'd accept that as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Answer is there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you have the [AWS_CLI_AUTO_PROMPT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html#envvars-list-aws_cli_auto_prompt) environment variable set somewhere in your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, or similar files.

As you can see in the AWS CLI auto-prompt [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-prompting.html#cli-usage-auto-prompt-configure), this variable overrides the `cli_auto_prompt` setting in the `~/.aws/config` file.

If things still look spooky after that, try completely uninstalling and reinstalling the AWS CLI.